# Constructors with Arrow Syntax

Tags: javascript

So, in the past few weeks, I've been writing quite a bit of Node-handled JavaScript, and I've found myself enjoying arrow functions much more for their look in my code (and the other obvious benefits, like lexical scoping, functional presentation, etc) I use them every where I possibly can in my code.

However, I've noticed that when writing constructors, you cannot use arrow syntax.

```
"use strict";

let foo = (x) => {
    this.something = x;
}

let newFoo = new foo(10);
```

will throw

```
let newFoo = new foo(10);
             ^

TypeError: (x) => {
    this.something = x;
} is not a constructor
```

Now, I guess my real question is: is this a deliberate design intention? Or is there something about the arrow syntax that I'm missing that makes this reasonable and expected?

Comment: It's quite deliberate, because of the semantics of `this` in arrow functions.

Comment: @Pointy So, it is a scoping issue rather than a design intention?

Comment: Read the accepted answer in the question I linked to, it explains in great detail.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I get it now.